# Proper credentials for node & s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My goal is to set up an S3 bucket that my node application can download objects from. I am new to building websites and api requests and have spent a lot of time reading up on AWS's documentation but am really confused.

What are the best ways to set up credentials so that my node application can connect to S3 and download the specific objects I need? Should I be using an iAm role? Are the iAm access keys then just stored on my local .aws/credentials file? So far I have been trying to run the code below with first my personal aws user's access keys, and then an iAm role's access keys, saved into my .aws/credentials file, but I keep getting `Access Denied` (stack trace below). Am I not setting up my credentials correctly? Thanks!

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'personal-account'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

var params = { Bucket: "my_bucket", Key: "testing.txt" }

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data);
});
```

Stack Trace:

```
 { AccessDenied: Access Denied
at Request.extractError (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:577:35)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
message: 'Access Denied',
code: 'AccessDenied',
region: null,
time: 2017-10-26T02:01:15.586Z,
requestId: '10371DCDBBC02508',
extendedRequestId: '0GC8BZ/39/eFOzWgTedHSFxhFSGBAMcZqxCVAlUxp8YamwBGeGZUZVe7Ti9O/6+BxhUTk9jb4hk=',
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 75.06631783335284 } 'AccessDenied: Access Denied
at Request.extractError (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:577:35)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)    
at Request.transition (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)    
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10    
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)    
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)    
at Request.callListeners (/Users/jemery62/dev/jimmyemery_com/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)'
```

## **UPDATE:**

Hi, I am still unable to get access to this file. My .aws/credentials looks like the following (I am using my personal-account profile, which pulls my IAm role):

```
[default] ; default profile
aws_access_key_id = defaultAccessKey
aws_secret_access_key = defaultSecretAccessKey
region = us-east-1

[personal-account] ; personal account profile
aws_access_key_id = personalAccessKey
aws_secret_access_key = personalSecretAccessKey
region = us-east-1
```

.aws/config:

```
[profile corp]
role_arn = corp-role-arn
region = us-east-1
source_profile = default
```

I'm not sure I understand too well how IAm policies work, but I have my IAm role set up with AdministratorAccess and the following profile:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to make additional changes to my .aws/config? Am I resourcing my credentials incorrectly or incorrectly trying to call the object I want?

## **UPDATE 2:**

I have posted a second question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966678/unable-to-download-s3-objects-with-node) to clarify exactly the issue I am experiencing at this moment, as I think this post I have made is starting to become a bit confusing.

Comment: `Key: "testing.txt"` will not fetch the content of `testing.txt`. Your key is literally this string, which may be why it doesn't work.

Comment: hey @JeremyThille I'm not sure I understand. Doesn't the key indicate the string name value of the file I want to fetch? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jimmy that comment is incorrect.  `Key` is the object key you want to fetch from the bucket.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot. Where do I find the proper object key that I want to fetch? I keep reading the docs but I can't find the details. Do I need to declare the object key as well for the bucket or just its character name?

Comment: The key is the path + filename, with no leading slash.  It seems as if you have that part right, if that's the name of the file in the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is running on EC2 then it should be using an EC2 instance profile. If it is running anywhere else then you should have an IAM user's keys configured in either `~/.aws/credentials` or in environment variables.

In either case, the IAM role or user should have an attached policy that gives it access to the S3 bucket and the objects within that bucket. If you have further issues then add the IAM policy you are using to your question.

Comment: @Jimmy I don't understand your update. How are you specifying the `personal-account` profile? And what is that stuff in your `.aws/config file`? What is the relevance of the `corp` profile in that config file? You can't be using a profile named `personal-account` and another named  `corp` at the same time. Have you read the documentation? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-new-and-standardized-way-to-manage-credentials-in-the-aws-sdks/ Why don't you stop all the profile stuff for now and just test with access key and secret key set in environment variables to verify the IAM account works.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB I agree. I'm new to this and realize that I failed to setup a config file related to my personal account. I'll test first with an environment variable and then go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I personally found that `loadFromPath` method to load credentials stored in a JSON formatted file result the most flexible way to do it.

You need indeed for an IAM role (choose carefully it access scope) to obtain both the `accessKeyId` and you `secretAccessKey`

So your JSON file should look like this:

```
{
  "accessKeyId": "IAM_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
  "secretAccessKey": "IAM_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('/path/to/credentials/aws.credentials.json');

var params = { Bucket: "my_bucket", Key: "testing.txt" }

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: using keys if if you are running code on ec2 is not best practice , use roles if your code is on ec2

Comment: Well, AWS infrastructure sure let you approach this with many ways. EC2 profiling is by far one of the most common practices.
But for me it seems more practical using JSON specially when working with servers outside AWS or if you dont want to spend time on configurating the console

Comment: @gtrenco if you use the JSON file then the same code won't be able to run on EC2 with an instance profile. That's why I prefer to use either the standard AWS credentials file or environment variables when running outside EC2, so that the same code works fine without any changes needed when you want to run it on EC2 with an IAM instance profile.

Answer (score 1):

The code below ended up working for me. It looks like the I needed to instantiate s3 *after* I configured AWS.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'personal-account'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = { Bucket: "my_bucket", Key: "testing.txt" }

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data);
});
```